# HtmlUnit Scraping Xpath from Div

Tags: java, xpath, web-crawler, htmlunit

I am trying to scrape the contents of the google movies page, i want the name of the theater, the address and the time.
As you can see in the google movie page each block of that information is inside a div with a class named theater, and inside that div theres the name, address and times of each theater.

So what i did was use htmlunit to extract a List of theater divs:

```
List<HtmlDivision> div =  (List<HtmlDivision>) page.getByXPath("//div[@class='theater']");
```

When printing the contents of the list i get the expected result:

```
System.out.println(div.get(0).asText());

Regal Battery Park Stadium 11
102 North End Avenue, New York, NY
1:00‎ ‎4:10‎ ‎7:20‎ ‎10:35pm‎
```

Now i want to split this information into name, address and times, the problem is that when i do:

```
System.out.println("Theater " + div.get(0).getByXPath("//div[@class='name']/a/text()"));
```

The result is the name of every single theater in the page:

```
Theater [Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, Regal Union Square Stadium 14, Cobble Hill Cinemas, Bow Tie Chelsea Cinemas, AMC Newport Centre 11, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, AMC Village 7, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, Cobble Hill Cinemas, AMC Loews 19th St. East 6, AMC Newport Centre 11, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, Regal Union Square Stadium 14, Bow Tie Chelsea Cinemas, AMC Newport Centre 11, AMC Loews 34th Street 14, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, City Cinemas Village East Cinema, AMC Loews 19th St. East 6, AMC Newport Centre 11, AMC Loews 34th Street 14, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, Regal Union Square Stadium 14, Bow Tie Chelsea Cinemas, AMC Newport Centre 11, AMC Loews 34th Street 14, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, Regal Union Square Stadium 14, Cobble Hill Cinemas, AMC Newport Centre 11, AMC Loews 34th Street 14, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, Regal Union Square Stadium 14, Cobble Hill Cinemas, Bow Tie Chelsea Cinemas, AMC Newport Centre 11, Regal Battery Park Stadium 11, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, City Cinemas Village East Cinema, AMC Loews Kips Bay 15, Regal E-Walk Stadium 13 & RPX, Pavilion Cinema, AMC Village 7, UA Court Street Stadium 12 & RPX, AMC Loews 19th St. East 6, AMC Newport Centre 11, AMC Loews 34th Street 14, AMC Loews Kips Bay 15, Regal E-Walk Stadium 13 & RPX, Frank Theatres - South Cove Stadium 12]
```

How is it possible that i am getting all the Theaters if i am doing a getByXpath inside an object that doesnt even have that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath to indicate that it meant to be relative to current context element which in this case is the first `div` (`div.get(0)`). Otherwise the XPath will ignore the context element and search for matching elements starting from the root :

```
div.get(0).getByXPath(".//div[@class='name']/a/text()")
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !! Thanks.